# How do I create a complex left outer join in Yii2?

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, yii2

How do I perform this query in Yii2?

```
SELECT `keyword`.`id`, `keyword`, `volume`, `cpc`, `competition`, `keyword_id` 
FROM `keyword` 
LEFT JOIN `ad_group_keyword` 
  ON keyword.id = ad_group_keyword.keyword_id 
  and ad_group_id = 1 
WHERE ((`keyword_id` IS NULL) 
  AND (NOT (`volume` IS NULL))) 
  AND (NOT (`cpc` IS NULL)) 
ORDER BY volume desc 
LIMIT 1;
```

I tried the following and many combinations but I can't get the `ON` part right.

```
$kw = Keyword::find()->select(['keyword.id', 'keyword', 'volume', 'cpc', 'competition', 'keyword_id'])->
  leftJoin('ad_group_keyword', 'keyword.id = ad_group_keyword.keyword_id', ['ad_group_id'=>1])->
  andWhere(['keyword_id'=>null])->
  andWhere(['not', ['volume' => null]])->andWhere(['not', ['cpc' => null]])->
  orderBy('volume desc')->asArray()->limit(1)->all();
```

The above generates this SQL, which is missing the second condition of the `ON`:

> SELECT `keyword`.`id`, `keyword`, `volume`, `cpc`, `competition`, `keyword_id` FROM `keyword` LEFT JOIN `ad_group_keyword` ON keyword.id = ad_group_keyword.keyword_id WHERE ((`keyword_id` IS NULL) AND (NOT (`volume` IS NULL))) AND (NOT (`cpc` IS NULL)) ORDER BY `volume` desc LIMIT 1

I also tried

```
leftJoin('ad_group_keyword', ['keyword.id'=>'keyword_id', 'ad_group_id'=>1])->
```

But it generates

> FROM `keyword` LEFT JOIN `ad_group_keyword` ON (`keyword`.`id`='keyword_id') AND (`ad_group_id`=1)

With 'keyword_id' in quotation marks, so it treats it as a string!

Docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#leftJoin()-detail

(This is why I hate dealing with ORM APIs. I spent all that time becoming proficient at SQL. Now you make me learn a whole new way of doing the same thing, and sometimes it's impossible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to your remark of having to deal with ORM API, you can use the `createCommand` approach. You can just use your raw sql query with this method. The difference is that you don't get `ActiveRecord[]` as a result but just `array[]` (which is usually fine for complex queries).

```
$sql = "SELECT `keyword`.`id`, `keyword`, `volume`, `cpc`, `competition`, `keyword_id` 
FROM `keyword` 
LEFT JOIN `ad_group_keyword` 
  ON keyword.id = ad_group_keyword.keyword_id 
  and ad_group_id = 1 
WHERE ((`keyword_id` IS NULL) 
  AND (NOT (`volume` IS NULL))) 
  AND (NOT (`cpc` IS NULL)) 
ORDER BY volume desc 
LIMIT 1;";

$params = [];

$kw = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql, $params)->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
leftJoin('ad_group_keyword', ['and', 'keyword.id = keyword_id', "ad_group_id = $adGroupId"])->
```